# Entity Framework model with a property indicating count of one to many relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

Let's say I have the following code first EF model:

```
public class Truck { public ICollection<Tire> Tires { get; set; } }
```

How would I create a property, HasTires, that is calculated by the database based on whether or not the truck has any tires?  My goal here is that I want to be able to determine if a truck has at least one tire without loading the tire objects.

I'm trying to avoid adding a column to the database that I would have to manage.

**EDIT:** I should also point out that I need to get a collection of Trucks back, potentially 100s or 1000s.

Answer (score 1):

You can get whole trucks with at least 1 tire like so

```
var TrucksWithAtLeastOneTire = context.Trucks.Where(g=> g.Tires.Count() > 0);
```

or just to check if a specific truck has at least one tire:

```
private bool TruckHasTire(int truckId) {
  return context.Trucks.Any(g=> g.Id == TruckId && g.Tires.Count() > 0);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that I need to get a collection of Trucks back regardless of whether or not they have any tires, but as part of that I need to know if each entity has any tires.  In some cases I may need 100s or 1000s.

Answer (score 1):

```
context.Trucks
    .Select( t => new 
    {
        Truck = t, 
        HasTires = t.Tires.Any()
    } );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try this

> Instead of `Count` you can use `Any` in this scenario
>   
>  This will only fetch `Trucks` with one tire.

```
var TrucksWithAtLeastOneTire = context.Trucks.Where(g=> g.Tires.Any());
```

Or you could project `Trucks and Tires`

```
var TruckAndTires = context.Trucks
                           .Where(g=> g.Tires.Any())
                           .Select(trk=>
                           {
                              truck = trk,
                              tires = trk.Tires,   
                           }.ToList();
```